# Using CASE statements to sort multiple values in QGIS Field Calculator

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, expression, land-use, if-statement

I am working with land use data in QGIS and have multiple values in a field (let's call the field "zoning") that I would like to categorize into a broader parent field called `"land_use"`. So, there are multiple values in the `"zoning"` field that can result in one value in the new `"land_use"` field. For instance, values "A1", "A2" and "E" in the `"zoning"` field should be labelled as "Residential" in the new `"land_use"` field. I also have many other values in the zoning field that I need to recategorize into the land use field and would like to do this using one expression if possible (e.g., "CO1" or "CEW" as "Commercial", etc.).

Following another thread, I wrote this code:

```sql
CASE
    WHEN  "stat_land_" = 'A1' OR "stat_land_" = 'A2' OR "stat_land_" = 'A9' OR "stat_land_" = 'E' OR "stat_land_" = 'E2'
        THEN 'Residential|'
END
||
CASE
    WHEN  "stat_land_" = 'C' OR "stat_land_" = 'C1'
        THEN 'Vacant Land|'
END
||
CASE
    WHEN  "stat_land_" = 'D1' OR "stat_land_" = 'D2' OR "stat_land_" = 'D3' OR "stat_land_" = 'E1' OR "stat_land_" = 'E3'
        THEN 'Agriculture|'
END
||
CASE
    WHEN  "stat_land_" = 'C04'
        THEN 'Commercial|'
    ELSE 'Other'
END
```

However, all my values end up in `NULL`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 17):

Use like this:

```
CASE

    WHEN  "stat_land_" IN ('A1', 'A2', 'A9', 'E', 'E2')
        THEN 'Residential' 
        
    WHEN  "stat_land_" IN ('C', 'C1')
        THEN 'Vacant Land'
        
    WHEN  "stat_land_" IN ('D1', 'D2', 'D3', 'E1', 'E3')
        THEN 'Agriculture'
        
    WHEN  "stat_land_" = 'C04'
        THEN 'Commercial'
        
    ELSE 'Other'
    
END
```

The problem is probably about operator `||`.

> operator `||`
>
> Joins two values together into a string.
> If one of the values is `NULL` the result will be `NULL`. See the `CONCAT` function for a different behavior.

Comment: to avoid typing the field name multiple times, you can use the IN operator:

```
CASE
    WHEN  "stat_land_" IN ('A1', 'A2', 'A9', 'E', 'E2') THEN 'Residential' 
    WHEN  "stat_land_" IN ('C', 'C1') THEN 'Vacant Land'  
    WHEN  "stat_land_" IN ('D1', 'D2', 'D3', 'E1', 'E3') THEN 'Agriculture' 
    WHEN  "stat_land_" = 'C04' THEN 'Commercial'  
    ELSE 'Other'
END 
```