# Using functions If and When

Tags: qgis, function

I am trying to find out which functions am I supposed to use, in order to get the values that I need.

The **Table** should look like this. I have all the values available, now I am trying to get different form of values in a column **text**.

[image]

What I am trying to achieve is next:

When **objekt** is "Nivelation", then **text** should have a value of **height** with added letter "m".

When **objekt** is "GR-A", then **text** should have the value "A".

When **objekt** is "Point" and there is Value in column **number**, then the **text** should have a combined value of "P-number"

When **objekt** is Line and there is Value in column **number**, then the **text** should combine those two and add a direction (North, Northeast etc..)

I was trying to use different functions, like if and when, but I am not familiar with QGIS that much.

Which functions should I use and how should I write these functions in order to achieve these results?

I am using QGIS version 3.22.9 Bialowieza

I tried writing when and if functions, however, I am not sure that I even know how these functions should I use to get what I need.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: "number" field is a compass bearing? Why should 33 get the value E?

Comment: Have you had a look at the tooltips in the fieldcalculator for `if()` and `case when`?

Comment: [case when](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_case.asp) should work

Comment: @Bera "number" field is sort of an ID of this line. It should get the value E, in order to know the direction from which it was photographed. 
I found the code for calculating bearing
(atan((xat(-1)-xat(0))/(yat(-1)-yat(0)))) * 180/3.14159 + (180 *(((yat(-1)-yat(0)) < 0) + (((xat(-1)-xat(0)) < 0 AND (yat(-1) - yat(0)) >0)*2)))

It is the direction of a line, and the direction of photographing is a whole other problem. That is a whole new set of values to import. Or somehow modifying the line to show the direction of the photo with starting and end points.

Answer (score 0):

After some time, I got back to this problem. Seems like **CASE WHEN** solves partially my problem. This is the result for the first two lines of a table. **||** are needed in order to solve multiple values.

CASE WHEN objekt = 'Nivelation' THEN "height" ELSE '' END
|| CASE WHEN objekt =  'GR-A'  THEN  'A' ELSE  ''  END

For some reason in a "text" which has string value, my height gets **point** instead of **comma**. So I used expression **replace**.

replace( "text", '.', ',' )

To add **m** as in **meter**, I found next solution, with the end of a expression being important, in order **not to annulate all** other values.

CASE WHEN objekt = 'Nivelation' THEN concat ( "text", ' m' ) ELSE "text" END

Comment: You dont need to repeat the CASE each time, you just have to put it at first then as many WHEN ...THEN...as you want, if needed one ELSE after the last  and you finish the case statement by END. See this question for an exemple of proper syntax https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/416884/using-case-statements-to-sort-multiple-values-in-qgis-field-calculator